# Cannot get jQuery scrollTo plugin to work OnClientClick

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I need help getting Ariel Flesler`s jquery scrollTo plugin to work. I can get it to work just fine if I do the following (note: this is a web forms site so the jquery is included on the master page):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var $paneTarget = $('#pane-target');  
        $('#ctl00_DetailsBoxHolder_LinkButton5').click(function () {
            var $target = $paneTarget.find('#div14');
            $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo($target, 800);
        });
    });
</script></head>
...
...
<ul>
<li>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server">
jQuery object</asp:LinkButton></li>
</ul>

<div id="pane-target">..bunch of elements...
<ul>..bunch more elements...
<li><div id="div14">etcetc</div></li>
..bunch more elements...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Ok, so that works -- great! However, I don`t want to bind right away to a button click event because in practice I have a repeater and I need to click on a repeater element to fire the the scrollTo function. So I removed the click binding in the script block and added an OnClientClick to my link button. I figured the following would work just fine:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dosomescrolling() {
       var $paneTarget = $('#pane-target');
       var $target = $paneTarget.find('#div14');
       $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo($target, 800);
    }
</script></head>
...
...
<ul>
<li>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" OnClientClick="dosomescrolling();">
jQuery object</asp:LinkButton></li>
</ul>

<div id="pane-target">..bunch of elements...
<ul>..bunch more elements...
<li><div id="div14">etcetc</div></li>
..bunch more elements...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Nope! I get the following error:

```
$paneTarget.stop(...).scrollTo is not a function
```

What gives??

Comment: After testing this a bunch it seems like scrollTo just doesn`t work OnClientClick. I would love to hear differently

Answer (score 0):

I would love to hear a better solution but (I couldn't find much documentation on this) it looks like the jQuery plugin simply isn`t loaded at the time OnClientClick fires. To alleviate this I just moved the entire plugin code into my OnClientClick function, which resolved the issue